# Install Multi php version on nginx

Tags: php, nginx, php-5.6, php-7.1

After I installed multi php version between php version 7.1.2 with php version 5.6 then I'm trying restart service by command

```
systemctl restart nginx php-fpm php56-php-fpm
```

I got this error:

```
Job for php56-php-fpm.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status php56-php-fpm.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So I tried this command:

```
systemctl status php56-php-fpm.service
```

Which gave me:

```
php56-php-fpm.service - The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/php56-php-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-09-11 10:44:19 +07; 2min 52s ago
Process: 54781 ExecStart=/opt/remi/php56/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
Main PID: 54781 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Sep 11 10:44:19 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The PHP FastCGI Process Manager...
Sep 11 10:44:19 localhost.localdomain systemd[54781]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /opt/remi/php56/ro...ory
Sep 11 10:44:19 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: php56-php-fpm.service: main process exited, code=ex...XEC
Sep 11 10:44:19 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP FastCGI Process Manager.
Sep 11 10:44:19 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit php56-php-fpm.service entered failed state.
Sep 11 10:44:19 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: php56-php-fpm.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

How can I fix this? What's going wrong?

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to have multiple versions of PHP? Why not just go with whatever the latest version installed is and uninstall the old one?

Comment: I have new website by php version 7.1.2 and I need to website 2 year ago by php version 5.6.

Comment: Check that each pool use a different socket and check selinux context, some information in https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/ else paste php-fpm/error.log

Comment: @MOSOKIM Rather than trying to maintain a dual PHP installation using a version that will be past its [extended support lifecycle](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) in 3 months, I recommend you instead [update your code](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php). With the exception of the removal of ext/mysql (if you were using it, which you shouldn't have been anyway), the changes required to migrate your code should be minimal. And even then, switching from ext/mysql to PDO is not as hard as it may seem once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
systemctl enable php56-php-fpm
```

---

```
systemctl start php56-php-fpm
```

---

If you gets error when start the second instance PHP-FPM (PHP 5.6), there might be the possibility of SELinux is blocking it. You can set the Selinux mode to permissive.

**To check SELinux status:**

```
getenforce
```

if it is enforcing, then set it to permissive mode:

```
setenforce 0
```

---

```
systemctl restart  nginx  php-fpm  php56-php-fpm
```